Error 405 when logging in after new installation of standalone
I'm brand new to CiviCRM. I have just spent the last couple of days trying to get standalone CiviCRM installed on a server at home. But I'm not having any luck getting it to work. I hope this is the right place to ask. I would really appreciated some help. I'm always looking for open source alternatives to commercial software so it would be marvellous if CiviCRM could be an option. What I have done so far is to install (on Linux - a Raspberry Pi 5 to be exact):

Apache2
PHP
MariaDB
I followed the instructions on https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/standalone/

I now get the login screen but when I try to log in I get a popup which says:
civicrm says unexpected error.

I'm getting this error in the browser console
1.  {error\_code: 405, error\_message: 'SECURITY: All requests that modify the database must be http POST, not GET.'}

and this error in the apache logs:
civicrm.local:80 192.168.0.99 - - [22/Dec/2024:20:13:04 +0000] "POST /civicrm/ajax/api4/User/login HTTP/1.1" 405 435 "http://civicrm.local/civicrm/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/130.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/115.0.0.0"

